# Use Django logging facility in settings.py

Tags: django, logging, error-logging, django-settings

My `settings.py` contains a lot of imports in `try`/`catch` blocks like:

```
try:
    import gcframe
except ImportError:
    # log gcframe is not available
    pass
```

etc.

I'd like to use Django logger to log which modules are missing, but [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/logging/) says:

> Logging is configured immediately **after** settings have been loaded.
>   Since the loading of settings is one of the first things that Django
>   does, you can be certain that loggers are always ready for use in your
>   project code.

Is there a way to create messages (log records) in `settings.py` and trigger the logging of these messages after settings have been loaded?

Comment: What is your situation where you need a large number of imports in your settings.py?

Comment: I have provided the use case.

Comment: I think @Ignacio addresses this with his short answer. The higher level system will be the one to catch the logging as the django processing is starting.

Answer (score 1):

Output on stderr is caught by the higher-level system.

```
print >>sys.stderr, 'zOMG!'
```